# How to fix different intent getting identified when input contains special characters

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In my LUIS application I have a 'Greeting' intent. The intent identified for 'hi' is 'Greeting' but for 'hi.......' some other intent is identified. 
After training the  'hi.......' as 'Greeting' it gets identified as 'Greeting' correctly. There are some other variants too with special characters which need to be trained to make it work.

How do I make this to identify as Greeting without training with special characters?
This is being used in Microsoft Bot Framework v3 in C#

Comment: Are you using Node or C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can either train your LUIS model with all possible variations that include special characters or you can strip out all of the special characters before you send it to LUIS. I would recommend the latter. Here is an example of how you would do that in Node.

```
turnContext.activity.text = turnContext.activity.text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "", "");
```

Hope this helps!